# Angular: "Resolve" generate an infinite Loop

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

We are inside the **App.module.ts** specifically in the section:

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
  {path: 'xxx/:xxx', component: XxxComponent},
  {path: '', component: HomepageComponent, resolve: {
      answerCallHttp: CallHttpResolve
    }},
  {path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent}
])
```

now let's go to resolve **CallHttpResolve** and make a simple Http Call:

```
resolve(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot
  ): Observable<any> | Promise<any> | any {
      return this.HttpClient.get(this.api + '/retailer', {
        headers: new HttpHeaders({
          'Auth': this.memory.getToken()
        }),
        params: new HttpParams().set('system_device', 'desktop').set('system_platform', this.getBrowserName())
      }).toPromise().then(value => {return value;});
  }
```

As never when run this code generates me an infinite loop of http requests? How can I stop this loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you please add `pathMatch: 'full'` to the Home route, and check if it resolves your issue?

i.e:

```
{path: '', component: HomepageComponent, pathMatch: 'full', resolve: {
  answerCallHttp: CallHttpResolve
}},
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a redirect to an 'home' path:

```js
RouterModule.forRoot([
    {path: 'xxx/:xxx', component: XxxComponent},
    {path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
    {path: 'home', component: HomepageComponent, resolve: {
        answerCallHttp: CallHttpResolve
    }},
    {path: 'error', component: ErrorComponent}
])
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to run a resolver and also want to perform redirection inside it, you can do like this

`

```js
{
        path: '',
        pathMatch: 'full',
        redirectTo: '',
        resolve: {
            yourresolver (you are redirecting to one of child route below from this resolver)
        },
        runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
    },
    enter code here
    {
        path: '',
        component: yourparentcomponent,
        children: [
            {
                path: child route,
                component: child component
            },
        ]
    }
```

{
path: '',
pathMatch: 'full',
redirectTo: '',
resolve: {
yourresolver (you are redirecting to one of child route below from this resolver)
},
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'paramsOrQueryParamsChange'
},

```
{
    path: '',
    component: yourparentcomponent,
    children: [
        {
            path: child route,
            component: child component
        },
    ]
}`
```